# Why RewriteRule not working without R flag in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have a Codeigniter project in `project` folder of web root.

```
www
www/.htaccess
www/project/.htaccess ( here are its contents https://pastebin.com/qBbZ0REj )
```

**www/.htaccess**

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^pg/fetchPG/(.*)$ /project/product_groups/fetchPG/$1 [L]
```

Relevant part of `www/project/.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

If I do

```
http://localhost/pg/fetchPG/?groupid=26&response=html&mode=graph&response=html
```

It should show the contents of

```
http://localhost/project/product_groups/fetchPG/?groupid=26&response=html&mode=graph&response=html
```

But it just shows me the `404` page of Codeigniter.

I thought Querystring is missing, but I tried printing $_GET in that 404 page and it was fine, it was coming along.

I replaced `[L]` with `[L, R]` and it works, it redirects to that URL, but I don't want users to see the final URL.

**PS:** I have dedicated server, I have control of everything, please suggest if  there any other way to accomplush my goal?

Comment: Is there perhaps a `/project` folder at the root of you file system?

Comment: @DusanBajic root of file system? No, `project` folder is in `www`, means its here in `www/project` .. please see question, i have tried to explain directory structure I have

Comment: Is the document root at `www` or `www/project`?

Comment: @OlafDietsche Its at `www` ... all projects are in `www`

Comment: There is no rule in `www/.htaccess` to rewrite to `www/project`. Is this done by `www/index.php`?

Comment: @OlafDietsche Holy shoot, I just incorrectly asked question,  actually its `www/project/.htaccess ( here are its contents https://pastebin.com/qBbZ0REj )` ... please re-read my entire question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it works with the [`R|redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) flag, is that with a redirect the client sends a new request, and as a consequence `REQUEST_URI` changes.

I assume, that CodeIgniter is configured to look at `REQUEST_URI` and not at `QUERY_STRING`, which corresponds to the rule in `www/project/.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

To fix it, change `uri_protocol` to `query_string` as described in the [user guide](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_b11.html?highlight=uri_protocol#step-5-edit-your-config-file)

> Lastly, add the following new item to the config file (and edit the option if needed):
>
> ```
> /*
> |------------------------------------------------
> | URI PROTOCOL
> |------------------------------------------------
> |
> | This item determines which server global
> | should be used to retrieve the URI string. The
> | default setting of "auto" works for most servers.
> | If your links do not seem to work, try one of
> | the other delicious flavors:
> |
> | 'auto'         Default - auto detects
> | 'path_info'    Uses the PATH_INFO
> | 'query_string'        Uses the QUERY_STRING
> */
>
> $config['uri_protocol'] = "auto";
> ```

In your case this should look like

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "query_string";
```

---

In order to preserve a query string, you might try `path_info` instead, e.g.

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "path_info";
```

But you must also change the rewrite rule in `www/project/.htaccess` to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Note, that there's no question mark (`?`) anymore.

Comment: your suggestion `$config['uri_protocol'] = "query_string";` takes my code to correct controller, but in the process all the query string is lost, its empty. `$_GET` only has `/product_groups/fetchPG/` in it ...

Comment: I even tried `[L,QSA]` but there is no Query String params, all are lost.

Comment: It should preserve the query string, although you might try `uri_protocol=path_info`.

Comment: I tried `uri_protocol=path_info` too but it didnt work , then I had to change `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]` of `.htaccess` of my Codeiginter and now everything is fine

Comment: Can you elaborate how removing `?` mark solved my problem and I will accept answer? FYI, I also had to `$config['enable_query_strings'] = true;` in my `config.php` file. I will accept anyways because you are the one who pointed me to look at config.php

Comment: With question mark, the request is passed as a query string. Without question mark, the request is appended to `index.php` and then CodeIgniter can read it as `PATH_INFO` variable.

Comment: Maybe, `enable_query_strings` is the real fix for your problem, and it might work with `uri_protocol=query_string too.